# Implementing Material-UI Table on a class component with custom pagination actions

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I wanna use the MATERIAL-UI table on a class component. In the official documentation, it's a functional component. I have watched many tutorials but everywhere it's a functional component. That's why I am facing many problems like react hooks can't be called in a class component etc.

I want to use MATERIAL-UI table **on a class component**.

I'm trying to add a MATERIAL-UI table that has some custom actions like changing rows per page & go to the next page or previous page? In the official documentation of MATERIAL-UI, there is a table like that with some custom actions.

Any leads, please.

**CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/great-ardinghelli-m6puh?file=/src/Company.js

Comment: try adding some code and explain what are you trying to achieve which is not achievable. there is certainly ways to do that

Comment: Add a material-ui table there
https://codesandbox.io/s/great-ardinghelli-m6puh?file=/src/Company.js

Answer (score 0):

here is the example how you can create Material UI table using class components

```
    class Company extends Component {
      render() {
        const classes = this.props;

        return (
          <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
              <TableBody>
                {rows.map((row) => (
                  <TableRow key={row.name}>
                    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                      {row.name}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                ))}
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </TableContainer>
        );
      }
    }
    export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(Company);
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-grothendieck-xp20r?file=/demo.js)

Comment: I know it will be worked fine but can you customize this a little bit? Like I wanna some custom actions like changing the rows per page & go to the next page or previous page. In the official documentation of material-ui, there has a table like that with some custom actions. I wanna implement that table.